# Problema con metodo indefindio intelephense

Tags: php

VSC me india error en la clase heredada y no me deja instanciar los métodos. resulta que en otras versiones de php (tengo la 8.1 ahora) no me salia ese error y funcionaba correctamente y ahora con esta versión no funciona. Necesito hacer un PDF tengo:

archivo librerias/fpdf.php

y por otro lado el archivo crear_pdf.php el cual contiene el siguiente código:

```php
ob_start();

include("librerias/fpdf.php");
require('conexion.php');


class PDF extends FPDF {
    function Header(){
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',20);
        $this->Cell(100);
    $this->Cell(70, 10, 'Lista Productos', 0, 0, 'C');
    $this->Ln(20);
    }
    //put logo
    public function headerTable() {
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
    $this->Cell(50,10,'Codigo ',1,0,'C');
    $this->Cell(50,10,'Producto',1,0,'C');
    $this->Cell(120,10,'Descripcion',1,0,'C');
    $this->Cell(50,10,'Precio',1,1,'C');
    $this->Ln(1);
}

 public function viewTable($datos_bd) {
        $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
        $consulta = mysqli_query($datos_bd, "SELECT * FROM libros");
        while($row=$consulta->fetch_assoc()) {
    $this->Cell(50,15,$row['id'],1,0,'C');
    $this->Cell(50,15,$row['nombre'],1,0,'C');
    $this->Cell(120,15,$row['isbn'],1,0,'C');
    $this->Cell(50,15,$row['precio'],1,1,'C');
    }
       
}

    }

$pdf = new FPDF();

$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage('L', 'A4',0);
$pdf->headerTable();
$pdf->viewTable($datos_bd);
$pdf->Output();

?>
```

Las llamadas a las funciones

```php
$pdf->headerTable();
$pdf->viewTable($datos_bd);
```

Me generan error de funciones indefinidas intelephense.(osea ambas funciones que se encuentras heredadas de FPDF en el archivo librerias/fpdf.php. entiendo que va por el lado de la herencia que me falta definir algo.

Estuve buscando pero la verdad no encuentro o entiendo que está ocurriendo exactamente.

Comment: Que mensaje de error te da? Si has cambiado de versión de PHP, revisa si la librería tiene soporte para esa versión, no vaya a ser que la que tienes instalada utilice alguna función obsoleta y tengas que actualizarla tambien

Comment: Así es habían actualizado la librería en la pagina oficial.

Comment: Pero atención,intelephense no te va a impedir correr el código. Sólo te avisa que estás usando un método que no reconoce. No es más que un LSP, así que en el peor de los casos tu código igual correrá.